# Disable keyboard events from svg inside html5 page

Tags: javascript, html, svg, keyboard-events

I import an svg file inside a html5 page. For mouse events we have the attribute pointer-events that we can set to false to stop events but there is not any equivalent attribute for keyboard events. I have a js functions "document.onkeydown" that I want to be able to prevent from firing.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a listener for the respective events and return false.

```
document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = document.onkeypress = function (e){
        return false;
}
```